# Powershell: Setting Encoding for Get-Content Pipeline

Tags: encoding, powershell

I have a file saved as UCS-2 Little Endian I want to change the encoding so I ran the following code:

```
cat tmp.log -encoding UTF8 > new.log
```

The resulting file is still in UCS-2 Little Endian.  Is this because the pipeline is always in that format? Is there an easy way to pipe this to a new file as UTF8?

Comment: So UCS-2 Little Endian is utf16-le.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets#64937):

```
Get-Content tmp.log | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 new.log
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this... It helped me figure out a problem reading an xml file encoded in UTF-8

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom

Comment: Get-Content hgrc.tmp | Out-File -Encoding ASCII hgrc saved my bitbucket script.  Thanks.

Answer (score 38):

I would do it like this:

```
get-content tmp.log -encoding Unicode | set-content new.log -encoding UTF8
```

My understanding is that the -encoding option selects the encdoing that the file should be read or written in.

Comment: "Get-Help Set-Content" does not identify -encoding as an option, but it does in fact work.

Comment: @jedatu: That's because this parameter comes from the FileSystem provider.

Comment: Why doesn't Get-Content respect the console encoding setting `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8`?

Answer (score 8):

load content from xml file with encoding.

(Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 $fileName)

Comment: Do not use `Get-Content` to read XML files, because this requires prior knowledge of the file encoding. It's much better to let the XML parser read the file on it's own, as this correctly deals with any encoding the file might have. `$xml = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument).Load($fileName)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading an XML file, here's an even better way that adapts to the encoding of your XML file:

```
$xml = New-Object -Typename XML
$xml.load('foo.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell's get-content/set-content encoding flag doesn't handle all encoding types.  You may need to use IO.File, for example to load a file using Windows-1252:

```
$myString = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($filePath, [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252))
```

[Text.Encoding::GetEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoding?view=net-5.0)
[Text.Encoding::GetEncodings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencodings?view=net-5.0)