# script to save file as unicode

Tags: unicode, powershell, cygwin

Do you know any way that I could programmatically or via scrirpt transform a set of text files saved in ansi character encoding, to unicode encoding?

I would like to do the same as I do when I open the file with notepad and choose to save it as an unicode file.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets and also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76482/powershell-setting-encoding-for-get-content-pipeline

Comment: Unicode is a *character set*, not an *encoding*.
UTF-8 is an *encoding* of the *character set* Unicode.
See if [this fine answer](https://superuser.com/a/762475) is of any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use iconv. On Windows you can use it under Cygwin.

```
iconv -f from_encoding -t to_encoding file
```

Comment: Why's the accepted answer related to Cygwin? The question is tagged as powershell...

Comment: Yes, at the begining I was looking for a powershell solution, but turns out that this worked really good for me and I could also use cygwin.

Anyway all the reponses given seem to be valid approaches

Answer (score 13):

This could work for you, but notice that it'll grab **every** file in the current folder:

```
Get-ChildItem | Foreach-Object { $c = (Get-Content $_); `
Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $c -Path ($_.name + "u") }
```

Same thing using aliases for brevity:

```
gci | %{ $c = (gc $_); sc -Encoding UTF8 $c -Path ($_.name + "u") }
```

Steven Murawski suggests using `Out-File` instead. The differences between both cmdlets are the following:

- `Out-File` will attempt to format the input it receives.
- `Out-File`'s default encoding is Unicode-based, whereas `Set-Content` uses the system's default.

Here's an example assuming the file `test.txt` doesn't exist in either case:

```
PS> [system.string] | Out-File test.txt
PS> Get-Content test.txt

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType          
-------- -------- ----                                     --------          
True     True     String                                   System.Object     

# test.txt encoding is Unicode-based with BOM
```

```
PS> [system.string] | Set-Content test.txt
PS> Get-Content test.txt

System.String

# test.txt encoding is "ANSI" (Windows character set)
```

In fact, if you don't need any specific Unicode encoding, you could as well do the following to convert a text file to Unicode:

```
PS> Get-Content sourceASCII.txt > targetUnicode.txt
```

`Out-File` is a "redirection operator with optional parameters" of sorts.

Comment: Using out-file will somehow cause an empty file. I am using PS V5.1

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be Get-Content 'path/to/text/file' | out-file 'name/of/file'.

[Out-File has an -encoding parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315303.aspx), the default of which is Unicode.

If you wanted to script a batch of them, you could do something like

```
$files = get-childitem 'directory/of/text/files' 
foreach ($file in $files) 
{
  get-content $file | out-file $file.fullname
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the System.IO.StreamReader(To read the file contents) class together with the System.Text.Encoding.Encoding(To create the Encoder object which does the encoding) base class.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new text file and write the bytes from the original file into the new one, placing a '\0' before each original byte (assuming the original text file was in English).

Answer (score -1):

pseudo code...

Dim system, file, contents, newFile, oldFile

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3 
Const AnsiFile = -2, UnicodeFile = -1

Set system = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject...

Set file = system.GetFile("text1.txt")

Set oldFile = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, AnsiFile)

contents = oldFile.ReadAll()

oldFile.Close

system.CreateTextFile "text1.txt"

Set file = system.GetFile("text1.txt")

Set newFile = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, UnicodeFile)

newFile.Write contents

newFile.Close

Hope this approach will work..