# Powershell '>' operator, change encoding?

Tags: python, windows, powershell

Is there a way to change the default encoding of the > operator in powershell? I'd like it to output as ANSI as UTF-8 for my requirements.txt:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
pip freeze | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 requirements.txt
```

or you can try

```
pip freeze > iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 in.txt > out.txt
```

you can read about [iconv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv)

Comment: @jeff try ISO-8859-1 for that

Comment: ut-File : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Encoding'. The argument "ISO-8859-1" does not belong to the set
unknown,string,unicode,bigendianunicode,utf8,utf7,utf32,ascii,default,oem" specified by the ValidateSet attribute.

Comment: @Jeff try utf-8-sig this one . i am learning about them . i have searched and saw this more useful link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898294/convert-utf-8-with-bom-to-utf-8-with-no-bom-in-python

Comment: I don't think it is supported by powershell.

Comment: @Jeff then try in python write a python code that converts.use std.in and std.out for this save the result in txt file.

Comment: @Jeff some useful links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76482/powershell-setting-encoding-for-get-content-pipeline