# How to fix an accented string [python]

Tags: python, string, unicode, unidecoder

I'm using a webapp to retrieve data from results of a game I play. As I'm brazilian and my language has some latin accented characters, most of the data I retrieve comes in a bad shape for use. Like:

Carlos Lopez = Carlos Lã³Pez

I searched internet and found ftfy as a good fixer for broken text. Anyway, I'm not really aware about unicode, ascii and stuff, so I used ftfy, and received as output the same errors I already have.

```
In[15]: ftfy.fix_text('Carlos Lã³Pez')
Out[15]: 'Carlos Lã³Pez'

ftfy.fix_encoding('Carlos Lã³Pez')
Out[16]: 'Carlos Lã³Pez'

ftfy.fix_text('Carlos Lã³Pez')
Out[17]: 'Carlos Lã³Pez'

print(ftfy.fix_text('Carlos Lã³Pez'))
Carlos Lã³Pez

print(ftfy.fix_encoding('Carlos Lã³Pez'))
Carlos Lã³Pez

ftfy.explain_unicode('Carlos Lã³Pez')
U+0043  C       [Lu] LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
U+0061  a       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER A
U+0072  r       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER R
U+006C  l       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER L
U+006F  o       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER O
U+0073  s       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER S
U+0020          [Zs] SPACE
U+004C  L       [Lu] LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
U+00E3  ã       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE
U+00B3  ³       [No] SUPERSCRIPT THREE
U+0050  P       [Lu] LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
U+0065  e       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER E
U+007A  z       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER Z

ftfy.explain_unicode(unidecode('Carlos Lã³Pez'))
U+0043  C       [Lu] LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
U+0061  a       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER A
U+0072  r       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER R
U+006C  l       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER L
U+006F  o       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER O
U+0073  s       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER S
U+0020          [Zs] SPACE
U+004C  L       [Lu] LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
U+0061  a       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER A
U+0033  3       [Nd] DIGIT THREE
U+0050  P       [Lu] LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
U+0065  e       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER E
U+007A  z       [Ll] LATIN SMALL LETTER Z

print(ftfy.fix_encoding(unidecode('Carlos Lã³Pez')))
Carlos La3Pez

print(ftfy.fix_text(unidecode('Carlos Lã³Pez')))
Carlos La3Pez
```

I'd like to know if there's any package to fix this kind of error, or if you could give me any lead why Carlos López turned into Carlos Lã³Pez. I'd apreciatte.

Comment: How did you obtain the string in the first place? Did you correctly `.decode()` the Web data?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I didnt know that the way I obtained it was really important. Actually, I did some mechanical work. The webapp has a "import table to csv" button that I'm using. The CSV files is generated with the "wrong" characters. What I'm trying to do is to "convert" this characters to the correct format again (I dont want to bother the admin of the site with this)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132318/how-do-i-correct-the-character-encoding-of-a-file

Comment: @MatteoT. Probably not.

Comment: Actually, I feel it's a duplicate. I will try the solutions they gave. I may have more insights about my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, that was tough :) Your string was in the wrong encoding *and* wrong character case, too.

```
s = 'Carlos Lã³Pez'
s.upper().encode('cp1252').decode().title()
#'Carlos López'
```

This code works in Python3, but not in Python2.

Comment: `'Carlos Lã³Pez'.replace("ã","Ã").encode('cp1252').decode()` may be better, I get 'Carlos LóPez'.

Comment: @MatteoT. Your solution works only for ã. There may be other non-ASCII letters in the string.

Comment: @DYZ that worked awsomely (also with other names)! Thanks very much, could you explain how you find this solution please? Or how was your thinking to solve it.

Comment: It was essentially a trial-and-error exercise. I came across the answer almost incidentally.