# (Text-) File that supports encoding

Tags: file, encoding, utf-8, persistence, file-type

The project I'm working on takes xml files and input streams and converts them to pdf's and text. In the unit tests I compare this generated text with a `.txt` file that has the expected output.
I'm now facing the issue of these `.txt` files not being encoded in UTF-8 and been written without persisting this information (namely umlauts).
I have read few articles on the topic of persisting and encoding `.txt` files. Including [correcting the encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132318/how-do-i-correct-the-character-encoding-of-a-file), [saving and opening files in Visual Studio with encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxfdkfke.aspx), and some more.
I was wondering if there is a `text file format` that supports meta information about encoding like xml or html for example does.
I'm looking for a solution that is:

- Easy adaptable to any coworker on the same team
- It being persitant and not depending on me choosing an encoding in an editor
- Does not require any additional exotic program
- Can be read without or only little modification of the `File` class and it's input reading of C#
- Does at least support UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Why not just agree that all text files will be UTF-8?

Comment: I think this is more a confiuration isse than an agreement. I see the possibility in it, yet I think a file that supports annotation might be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM) is sometimes used for this purpose. Systems that process Unicode are required to strip off this metadata when passing on the text.  `File.ReadAllText` etc do this. A BOM should exist only at the beginning of files and streams.

A BOM is sometimes conflated with encoding because both affect the file format and BOM applies only to Unicode encodings. In Visual Studio, with UTF-8, it's called "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001".

Some C# code that demonstrates these concepts:

```
var path = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".txt";
File.WriteAllText(path, "Test", new UTF8Encoding(true, true));
Debug.Assert(File.ReadAllBytes(path).Length == 7);
Debug.Assert(File.ReadAllText(path).Length == 4); // slightly mushy encoding detection
```

However, this doesn't get anyone past the agreement required when using text files. The fundamental rule is that a text file must be read with the same encoding it was written with. A BOM is not a communication that suffices as a complete agreement for text files in general.

Test editors almost universally adopt the principle that they should guess a file's character encoding first, and—for the most part—allow users to correct them later. Some IDEs with project systems allow recording which encoding a file actually uses.

A reasonable text editor would preserve both the encoding and the presence of a Unicode BOM for existing files.

It seems that you're after a universal strategy. Unfortunately, the history of the concept of a text file doesn't allow one.