# Charset conversion from XXX to utf-8, command line

Tags: command-line, encoding, scripting, character-encoding

I have a bunch of text files that are encoded in ISO-8851-2 (have some polish characters). Is there a command line tool for linux/mac that I could run from a shell script to convert this to a saner utf-8?

Comment: Most likely ISO-885**9**-2. ISO 8851 speaks about butter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to convert text files between character sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`iconv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html), for example like this:

```
iconv -f LATIN1 -t UTF-8 input.txt > output.txt
```

Some more information:

- You may want to specify `UTF-8//TRANSLIT` instead of plain `UTF-8`. To quote the manpage:

  > If the string **`//TRANSLIT`** is appended to *to-encoding*, characters being converted are transliterated when needed and possible.  This means that when a character cannot be represented in the target character set, it can be approximated through one or several similar looking characters.  Characters that are outside of the target character set and cannot be transliterated are replaced with a question mark (?) in the output.
- For a full list of encoding codes accepted by `iconv`, execute `iconv -l`.
- The example above makes use of shell redirection. Make sure you are *not* using a shell that mangles encodings on redirection – that is, do not use PowerShell for this.

Answer (score 10):

```
recode latin2..utf8 myfile.txt
```

This will overwrite `myfile.txt` with the new version.  You can also use recode without a filename as a pipe.

Comment: Way more efficient than accepted answer, because iconv won't replace the same file, even using -o or output redirects.

Answer (score 3):

GNU ['libiconv'](http://directory.fsf.org/project/libiconv/) should be able to do the job.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it'd be easier than I thought!