# PowerShell script to get UTF8?

Tags: exchange-server, powershell, utf-8

We have a PowerShell script which creates an user in Microsoft Exchange and Active Directory.

We get the user's data by a preformated txt which serves as sort of CSV with:

```
$data = import-csv signup.txt
```

But the problem is that, as we are from Spain, sometimes it arises the character `ñ` which isn't picked up by the script and generates a bad username and bad data. So, we put it with N and then enter in Exchange and we change it from there again.

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: Experiment with `$csvdata = get-content -encoding windows-1250 signup.txt` and the like.

Comment: Get-Content : Cannot bind parameter 'Encoding'. Cannot convert value "windows-1
250" to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemCmdletProviderEncoding" d
ue to invalid enumeration values. This doesn't work

Comment: Get-Content allows those encodings "Unknown, String, Unicode, Byte, BigEndianUnicode, UTF8, UTF7, Ascii"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend converting the file to UTF-8. Because the import-csv cmdlet works with it.

I usually create an empty file in notepad++ with UTF-8 encoding and copy the text from the other file. 
Or as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets#64937)

```
Get-Content signup.txt -Encoding Ascii | Out-File signup_utf8.txt -Encoding UTF8
Import-Csv signup_utf8.txt
```