# How to convert ISO8859-15 to UTF8?

Tags: linux, bash, text

I have an Arabic file encoded in [ISO8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15). How can I convert it into UTF8?
I used `iconv` but it doesn't work for me.

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-15 -t UTF-8 Myfile.txt
```

I wanted to attach the file, but I don't know how.

Comment: Does `iconv` print an error message, or does it convert incorrectly?  (Incidentally, you might *accept* more of the answers you have received to earlier questions.  The answerers would appreciate this.)

Comment: No it doesn't print an error. I mean it converts the file incorrectly.  I checked the encoding of the file, and found it ISO-8859-15.

Comment: how did u determine it to be ISO-8895-15?

Comment: I opened the file, tried to Save As it. In the window appeared, the encoding of the file was ISO-8859-15. Is there another way to determine the encoding of the file?

Comment: ISO-8895-15 is a single byte character set, unless the msb is on for the byte, it looks exactly like the UTF-8 version.

Comment: So How I can change encoding of the file to see its characters correctly. I mean, when I open the file, its characters aren't shown correctly, and I couldn't read the file...

Comment: Plain text files don't include any information about the encoding used; it's just a sequence of bytes. The program that opens the file is responsible for inferring the encoding. That said, perhaps there is a special string you can include in the file that your program can  use as a hint.

Comment: whatever tool you use to view the file mostly likely sensitive to your locale, you should make sure your locale is the same as what you think the file is before attempting to view it.

Comment: ISO 8859-15 cannot represent Arabic text. Perhaps you mean 8859-6 or some legacy encoding? See, for a start, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-6

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Could it be that your file is not ISO-8859-15 encoded? You should be able to check with the file command:

```
file YourFile.txt
```

Also, you can use iconv without providing the encoding of the original file:

```
iconv -t UTF-8 YourFile.txt
```

Comment: How would the file command be able to tell you which encoding is appropriate to understand the file's content?

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk I don't think it does.  The man page says this:  "If no from-encoding is given, the default is derived from the current locale's character encoding."  So I believe HighKing's comment about not providing the encoding of the original file is wrong.

Comment: The file utility do not always guess the correct encoding. You need to manually to judge the content if it is understandable by opening the file with different encoding.

Comment: its worth a try without specifying the source encoding - worked for me

Answer (score 37):

I found this to work for me:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-14 Agreement.txt -t UTF-8 -o agreement.txt
```

Comment: while doing ``file myfile.txt``, it gives ``ISO-8859``. So, i have tried with yours (except ``-14``). It shows ``ISO-8859 is not supported``. And finally just I have added ``-14`` along with ``ISO-8859-14`` and worked..

Comment: I have seen usually ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 14):

I have ubuntu 14 and the other answers where no working for me

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 in.tex -o out.tex
```

I found this command [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64889/2916247)

Comment: That's the same as OP aside from you seem to be starting with a more common character set. Annoyingly Google seems to have ignored the 5 at the end of ISO-8859-15 in the title when searching for ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 9):

**We have this problem and to solve**

Create a script file called to-utf8.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
TO="UTF-8"; FILE=$1
FROM=$(file -i $FILE | cut -d'=' -f2)
if [[ $FROM = "binary" ]]; then
 echo "Skipping binary $FILE..."
 exit 0
fi
iconv -f $FROM -t $TO -o $FILE.tmp $FILE; ERROR=$?
if [[ $ERROR -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "Converting $FILE..."
  mv -f $FILE.tmp $FILE
else
  echo "Error on $FILE"
fi
```

Set the executable bit

```
chmod +x to-utf8.sh
```

Do a conversion

```
./to-utf8.sh MyFile.txt
```

If you want to convert all files under a folder, do

```
find /your/folder/here | xargs -n 1 ./to-utf8.sh
```

Hope it's help.

Comment: Really useful to convert a bunch of files to UTF8 in place.. since iconv will not work if the input and output file "are the same". Thankyou!

Comment: Using this script on a java project I get that ".class" are not supported.. and they are not binary from the file command. Anyway no need to convert those file...

Answer (score 6):

I got the same problem, but i find the answer in  [this page](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/iconv-conversion-from-%60iso-8859%27-is-not-support-why-this-happens-848124/)! it works for me, you can try it.

```
iconv -f cp936 -t utf-8
```

Comment: For files created in Windows with Chinese Simplified codepage, this is the only answer that works.

Answer (score 3):

in my case, the `file` command tells a wrong encoding, so i tried converting with all the possible encodings, and found out the right one.

execute this script and check the result file.

```
for i in `iconv -l`
do
   echo $i
   iconv -f $i -t UTF-8 yourfile | grep "hint to tell converted success or not"
done &>/tmp/converted
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ISO-8859-9 encoding:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-9 Agreement.txt -t UTF-8 -o agreement.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Iconv just writes the converted text to stdout. You have to use `-o OUTPUTFILE.txt` as an parameter or write stdout to a file. (`iconv -f x -t z filename.txt > OUTPUTFILE.txt` ***or*** `iconv -f x -t z < filename.txt > OUTPUTFILE.txt` in some iconv versions)

```
Synopsis

iconv -f encoding -t encoding inputfile

Description

The iconv program converts the encoding of characters in inputfile from one coded character set to another. 
**The result is written to standard output unless otherwise specified by the --output option.**

--from-code, -f encoding

Convert characters from encoding

--to-code, -t encoding

Convert characters to encoding

--list

List known coded character sets

--output, -o file

Specify output file (instead of stdout)

--verbose

Print progress information.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm well aware that this question is over a decade old; nevertheless, I'd like  to give another suggestion, namely, to use [`recode`](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Recode) — an old, but well-maintained utility tool, and which not only fully supports `libiconv`, but it adds a few more character encodings, and, perhaps most interestingly, it allows in-place replacements of transcoded files — this means that the many solutions provided above that require making a copy first and then moving the final file to its destination (with the side-effect that the date of last modification of the original gets lost...) are not necessary.

I find `recode` especially useful for changing ancient static HTML files from ISO-Latin-1 into UTF-8, *while preserving the original date*, and doing so recursively, if needed.

`recode` is available from most package managers (Homebrew on macOS, apt on Debian/Ubuntu) but can also be retrieved from [Reuben Thomas' GitHub repository](https://github.com/rrthomas/recode/), if needed, and locally compiled; it's being actively maintained and does regular releases.