# php string replace is not working

Tags: php

I want to replace some strings in a sql file. I've written a php script that should do that. But after I added the while for looping trough that big file (1.2GB) the replacing is not working anymore.

```
$reading = fopen('m.sql', 'r');
$writing = fopen('m.tmp', 'w');

$search = array("Ã¤",
    "Ã„",
    "Ã¶",
    "Ã–",
    "Ã¼",
    "Ãœ",
    "â‚¬",
    "Â§",
    "ÃŸ",
    "latin1_general_ci",
    "CHARSET=latin1",
    "â€š",
    "â€ž",
    "â€˜",
    "â€™",
    "â€œ",
    "â€",
    "Â©",
    "Â®");

$replace = array("ä",
    "Ä",
    "ö",
    "Ö",
    "ü",
    "Ü",
    "€",
    "§",
    "ß",
    "utf8_general_ci",
    "CHARSET=utf8",
    "‚",
    "„",
    "‘",
    "’",
    "“",
    "”",
    "©",
    "®");

if ($reading) {
    // read one line or 4096 bytes, whichever comes first
    while (($dateiinhalt = fgets($reading, 4096)) !== false) {
        // replace in that and write to output file
        fwrite($writing, str_replace($search, $replace, $dateiinhalt));
    }
    if (!feof($reading)) { // fgets() failed, but not at end of file
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($reading);
    fclose($writing);
}

echo "done";
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: okay and what could be a solution?

Comment: Isn't it an option to convert the encoding directly by an existing tool e.g. on the linux command line?

Comment: and what could that be?

Comment: now I have mixed latin1 and utf8 (not my fail got it like this) at the end I want to have proper utf8 with all special chars

Comment: There are several tools, you could find by a search engine - one of them: iconv - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316986/how-to-convert-iso8859-15-to-utf8

Comment: Yes I tried iconv but the result isn't fine. When I have used this  `$dateiinhalt = file_get_contents("./m.sql");` it worked fine. Problem is that the file is to big for file_get_contents

Comment: `fgets` read 4096 bytes, it can cut part of symbol, one symbol != one byte.

Comment: okay can you tell me how I can fix that?

Comment: why dos it work with `file_get_contents` is there a way to use `file_get_contents` in this large file?

Comment: It should work with reading the file line by line as well. Otherwise I only guess there might be a BOM at the start of file.(?) However, afaik PHP does not care about a BOM. Are you only dealing with *one* big file?

Comment: how can I check if there is a bom when I can't open the file?

Comment: how could it look like in recode? tried `recode ../utf8 m.sql` not working ...

Comment: Have you tried `recode latin1..utf8 m.sql`

Comment: If none of the above solves you problem, you could take a look at [mb_* functions](php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php)

Comment: recode has broken the file. its emty now 

which mbstring function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113845/discussion-between-quasimodos-clone-and-felix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to change php version from 5.5 to 7