# Convert files between UTF-8 and ISO-8859 on Linux

Tags: linux, iconv

Every time that I get confronted with Unicode, nothing works. I'm on Linux, and I got these files from Windows:

```
$file *
file1: UTF-8 Unicode text
file2: ISO-8859 text
file3: ISO-8859 text
```

Nothing was working until I found out that the files have different encodings. I want to make my life easy and have them all in the same format:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859 file1 > test
iconv: conversion to `ISO-8859' is not supported
Try `iconv --help' or `iconv --usage' for more information.
```

I tried to convert to ISO because that's only 1 conversion + when I open those ISO files in gedit, the German letter "ü" is displayed just fine. Okay, next try:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859 -t UTF-8 file2 > test
iconv: conversion from `ISO-8859' is not supported
Try `iconv --help' or `iconv --usage' for more information.
```

but obviously that didn't work.

Comment: That's because "ISO-8859" isn't an encoding. Did you maybe mean ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15? Or [one of the other 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859#Table)?

Comment: Also there might be problem with your utf-8 source file. It can contain character, that can't be represented in ISO-8859. Converting to utf-8 will be much safer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ISO-8859-x (Latin-1) encoding only contains very limited characters, you should always try to encode to UTF-8 to make life easier.

And utf-8 (Unicode) is a superset of ISO 8859 so it will be not surprised you could not convert UTF-8 to ISO 8859

It seems command `file` just give a very limited info of the file encoding

You could try to guess the from encoding either ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15 or the other from 2~14 as suggested in the comment by @hobbs

And you could get a supported encoding of `iconv` by `iconv -l`

If life treats you not easy with guessing the real file encoding, [this silly script might help you out :D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36619843/2288944)

Comment: @user3182532 ISO 8859 is the name of a standard with 16 parts that specify 16 different encodings (with some commonalities but various differences). `file` is telling you that it doesn't *know* which one it is. This is the general problem with 8-bit encodings —- it's easy enough to tell that you have an 8-bit encoding, but figuring out *which* one without prior knowledge is pure guesswork. Try them and see which one comes out right. 8859-15 is a good first guess.

Comment: "utf-8 (Unicode) is a superset of ISO 8859" ... *I think this is not true*. Could you please cite or explain, because in my experience, a file saved as `iso-8859-1` interpreted as if it were `utf-8` will definitely come out wrong.

Comment: @Stewart the set of characters encoded by Unicode **is** a superset of the set of characters in each of the ISO-8859 charsets. The characters are encoded differently, though.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann @amnotstrong There is a lot of confusion going around here. UTF-8 is _not_ Unicode, UTF-8 _is_ an encoding of Unicode. The way UTF-8 encodes Unicode codepoints means that it _is_ a superset of ASCII however. All valid ASCII characters are identically coded in UTF-8, e.g. `A` is encoded as decimal `65` in both ASCII and UTF-8. It is also encoded as `65` in all ISO8859 charsets because they are _also_ supersets of ASCII. But UTF-8 is _not_ a superset of any ISO8859 charsets. It _is_ possible to convert from any ISO8859 charset to UTF-8 _because_ UTF-8 encodes all of Unicode.

Comment: I guess the word "superset" is a bit too stretched here. Unicode is a set of characters, each with a number (called code point). UTF-8 (and the other UTFs) are an encoding of the unicode characters as bytes. ASCII and ISO-8859-x are character sets (each with different characters) and encodings of these characters into bytes. Unicode is a superset of all these character sets, but the encoding in UTF-8 is different than the encoding in ISO-8859-x. ASCII (as a character set) is a subset of the ISO-8859-x, and also of Unicode, and ASCII (as an encoding) is a "subencoding" of ISO-8859-x and UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

As in other answers, you can list out the supported formats

```
iconv -l | grep 8859
```

A `grep` will save your time to find which version of your encoding is/are supported. You can provide the `<number>` as in my example or `ISO` or any expected string in your encoding.