# Text corrupt after changing the Eclipse to UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding

I had to change the Eclipse Indigo encoding to UTF-8. Now all the spécial characters as éàçè are replaced with �.

I can do a search and replace but I wonder if there is better solution.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need project-specific encoding, then.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets as this seems to be what you want

Comment: @MarcoTopolnik he has changed the encoding, now he has to deal with the broken chars. If he did want another encoding i assume he would have left it as it was before ;)

Comment: Changing the encoding in Eclipse doesn't change your existing files : it only changes the way Eclipse reads them. What you need is to convert your old files to UTF-8 as well as configuring Eclipse. There are some tools to do that and you may write a small java program too.

Comment: @dystroy that's true, because when I open a class with NotePad++, the characters are displayed properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the encoding in Eclipse doesn't change your existing files : it only changes the way Eclipse reads them.

What you need is to convert your old files to UTF-8 as well as configuring Eclipse.

There are some tools to do that and you may write a small java program too.

If you want to use an existing tool, here's the first I found : http://www.marblesoftware.com/Marble_Software/Charco.html (you could find a better one for your (unspecified) OS.

If you want to write a tool yourself (about 20 LOC), the thing to know is that you must :

- [read the file with their initial charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder%29)
- [write the files in UTF-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder%29)

Here's the core of the operation :

```
  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(...), "you have to know it"));
  writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(...), "UTF-8"); 
  String line;
  while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
     writer.write(line);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend notepad++ for conversion. This is an editor which has some very useful/powerful view and conversion tools to troubleshoot charsets.
Also some more "swiss-knife"-like functions (file comparison, advanced search and replace and many more...)

[notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: It's sad, that a large tool like eclipse does not have this functionality built in.

Answer (score 0):

Just only need alt + enter then chooses resource UTF-8

Comment: Even neon 3 can't do the transfer automatically. First change the resource to let's say ISO-8859-1 or depending whatever encoding the file actually is, cut the text to clipboard and save the file empty. Don't forget to close the editor. Then do the alt + enter trick and change the file encoding, open the file and paste the content back.