# LInux shell: conditional conversion of character encoding, multiple text files

Tags: linux, bash, character-encoding, ascii, utf-16

The situation:
I have a bunch of text files (.csv, to be precise), around 20000 that differ in character encoding: `file -i *.csv` gives me `charset=us-ascii` for most, but some are `utf-16le`.

The goal:
I want them all to be encoded the same way, us-ascii here. I think of a one-liner that checks for each file in the directory the encoding, and if it is `utf-16le`, it converts it to `us-ascii`.

I only started to learn bash programming a few day ago, so this one still escapes me. Is it possible, something like running file -i on each file (did that), capturing the return value, check what encoding is given and if it is not us-ascii, convert it?

Thanks for helping me understand how to do that!

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions don't care about the mixture of files, which sounds like a solution in the sense of:

```
for F in *.csv; do
    if [ `file -i "$F" | awk '{print $3;}'` = "charset=utf-16" ]; then
        iconv -f UTF-16 -t US-ASCII "$F" > "u.$F"
    fi
done
```

What makes it easier is the identity of us-ascii and utf-16 in the first few (128) characters - so if the file really is us-ascii, the conversion would not do any harm.

Answer (score 1):

Pls try the following command:

```
iconv -f FROM-ENCODING -t TO-ENCODING *.csv
```

and replace `FROM-ENCODING` and `TO-ENCODING` with appropriate values.

You can use the following script, or something similar for your needs.

```
for file in  *.csv
do
    iconv -f FROM-ENCODING -t TO-ENCODING "$file" > "$file.new"
done
```

You can also use `recode` command.

```
recode FROM-ENCODING..TO-ENCODING file.csv
```

Finally, look at this [Best way to convert text files between character sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets) if you are interested in learning more about `iconv` and/or `recode`

Comment: Parsing the output of ls is harmful, use globbing.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Yes, when filenames have spaces, this can be a problem....thanks.

Comment: You also need to quote your variables, otherwise it doesn't fix anything ;-)

Comment: I only see $file, but if there are others feel free to quote them as well. Always quote, especially when dealing with filenames.

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong. Try yourself with a file that contains spaces.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Thanks a lot for helping to improve the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This will convert any non-us-ascii encoded `*.csv` files to us-ascii:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.csv;do
    charset=`file -i README.md |grep -o 'charset=.*'|cut -d= -f2`
    if [ "$charset" != "us-ascii" ];then
      echo "$f $charset -> us-ascii"
      iconv -f "$charset" -t us-ascii < "$f" > "$f.tmp" \
        && mv "$f.tmp" "$f"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Please quote your variables to account for spaces in filenames.