# Android How to display french letters (like- é,à etc.) using UTF-8 or else?

Tags: android, utf-8, locale

I know this is old question but I am not satisfied with answers given before.
My question is how to display french letters (like- é,à etc.) using UTF-8 or any technique.

Currently these are displaying "?".

My code is:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    if(CommonUtilities.prefs.getString("KEY_LOCALE", "fr").equalsIgnoreCase("fr")){
        is = getAssets().open("terms_txt_fr.txt");  
    }else{
        is = getAssets().open("terms_txt_en.txt");
    }

    String term_tx =convertStreamToString(is);
    String valueUTF8 = new String(term_tx.getBytes(), "UTF-8");

    terms_tx.setText(valueUTF8);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, your terms_txt_fr.txt is saved as UTF-8?

Comment: @flx, not sure this is only simple text file.how can i do that

Comment: did my answer work out for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is fine, but you need to make sure, your input is UTF-8 encoded.

There are a lot of methods how to do it. Each of them is specific to your environment like your operating system. A good summary is given here:
[Best way to convert text files between character sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)

On Linux (I guess on OSX it's the same) you do:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-15 -t UTF-8 in.txt > out.txt
```

Most good text editors have options for how to save files. You might want to check that too.
In modern operating systems UTF-8 should be the default.