# Change encoding in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, encoding

I was working on my project in Windows using Eclipse (and I didn't check that my encoding was CP-1251). Now am going to work with my project in Linux with Eclipse too, but with UTF8 encoding, so all my comments are now non readable.

Can I just reconvert them into UTF using Eclipse?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set up the encoding used by eclipse in the Preferences section

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Text file encoding

You can also override it for a single project only if that is the only project you are having trouble with.

Comment: Yes, but I want to change all my project encoding to UTF-8. And in this case my comments (on Russian) will be represented as unreadable symbols. I need to decode my CP1251 text to utf-8 with my comments.

Comment: In this case you need to convert the whole file. And so do it one by one (but you can write a little script easily)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets

Answer (score 1):

There is a **plugin for Eclipse** "Autodetect Encoding" - you can detect/convert the encoding in files. It can be found in the Help->Marketplace...

I just started testing, but it works so far.

Hint: sometimes you need to change the detector to ICU4j

And even if the convert does not work in a current document (because of detection) you can do this:
<kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> on one enconding switch to another and <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> it will paste correct then save.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to change the encoding for some `.properties` files.

I guess it works for other file types as well.

What I did and worked perfectly is:

Go to Window --> Preferenes --> General --> Content Types --> (Expand) Text--> Find `Java Properties File` --> Changed Default Encoding to `UTF-8` --> Clicked `Update`

Here is a picture:

[image: preview]

I do not know if this option exists in previous versions, but my version is [2020 - 06](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-06).