# print non-English String in Java

Tags: java, string, encoding, non-english

When I'm printing the movie name "Yôjinbô" (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055630/?ref_=chttp_tt_107) that contains some non-English characters, it appears to be "YÃƒÂ´jinbÃƒÂ´" in the output window in eclipse.

I cannot find any encoding setting in eclipse or the project properties.
How to correctly print the movie name?

-------------------- update -------------------

I found where the problem happened. The following is the code to get the movie info from omdbapi.com
When I print the line after reader.readLine(), the name is wrong.

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("movies/movie_" + i + ".txt"), "utf-8"));
sb = new StringBuilder();
ret = new StringBuilder();
title = URLEncoder.encode(movieNames[i], "UTF-8");
sb.append("http://www.omdbapi.com/?");
sb.append("t=").append(title).append("&");
sb.append("y=").append(year).append("&");
sb.append("plot=").append(plot).append("&");
sb.append("r=").append(r);
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
String url = sb.toString();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

String line = reader.readLine(); // <-------- wrong here
while (line != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    writer.write(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

But when I paste the url (http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Y%C3%B4jinb%C3%B4&y=&plot=short&r=json) directly in the chrome, the response is correct.

-------------------  problem solved -------------------

The only thing I need to do is to set "UTF8" when creating the InputStreamReader, as follows

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF8"));
```

Thanks for all your help.

------------------- more update -------------------

It turns out that FileReader and FileWriter implicitly use the system's default character encoding, which may cause problem, and should be replaced by alternatives.

```
// br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)); // <---- cause encoding problem here
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename), "UTF-8"));
```

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42

Comment: Does `System.out.println("Yôjinbô");` work?

Comment: Yes. Well, I'm checking the steps of string processing. It involves some file writing and reading operations, which may cause the encoding problem.

Comment: If you provide a bit of source it code might be helpful.

Comment: try to look about ascii codes? look at HEX and corresponding Symbols .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751791/how-to-change-default-text-file-encoding-in-eclipse) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262519/change-encoding-in-eclipse) can help you.

The web is plenty of other posts about your issue. Search for it.

Comment: Thanks, I've found the solution.