# cmd - Open file and save it - script

Tags: batch-file, encoding, utf-8, cmd

I need to open a .csv file and instantly save it with the same name (overwrite it) using a .bat.

This may sound stupid but it is the easiest way that I've found to change that .csv file codification (from ANSI to UTF-8).

If I type notepad file-name.csv it opens the .csv file, but how do I save it now?

Comment: Why do you need to open and save it ?

Comment: @Jidder The .csv file is downloaded from Google Drive and It has ANSI codification. If I open that file with Notepad and save it, it codification changes to UTF-8. That's why I need a script to do this process automatically.

Comment: You say `.bash` (which is a Linux console environment) but at the same time you mention "notepad" which is a Windows tool. Which operating are you using? In Linux you can use `iconv` to convert the encoding of a text file.

Comment: @user2864740 I need to open the file with Notepad because the codification of the file changes from ANSI to UTF-8 when I open it with Notepad and save it.

Comment: Since you have `bash` installed, I take it mingw/cygwin is available? [I would probably see this then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets) (note that even a PowerShell solution is provided). You're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I meant .bat file. Sorry. I'm working on Windows 8.1

Comment: You can use the Windows port of the iconv tool: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name THANKS.. that worked.. Can you type it as a answer so I can vote it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Windows port of the Linux tool `iconv` which can convert text files from one encoding to another.

The [gnuwin32 project](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net) has ports of all major GNU utilities, including `iconv` which can be downloaded as a single package from here:

- http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm

Answer (score 1):

For a pure script solution, this is a hybrid batch/javascript solution (adapted from a previous vbs answer). Adapt as needed and save as `.cmd` file.

```
@if (@this==@isBatch) @then
@echo off

    cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%~f0" ^
            /input:"input_file.csv" ^
            /output:"output_file.csv" ^
            /from:"x-ansi" ^
            /to:"utf-8"

    exit /b

@end
var adTypeText = 2;
var adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2;

var inputFile = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item('input');
var outputFile = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item('output');

var from = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item('from');
var to = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item('to');

var inputStream  = WScript.CreateObject('adodb.stream');
    with (inputStream){
        Type = adTypeText;
        Charset = from;
        Open();
        LoadFromFile( inputFile );
    }

var outputStream = WScript.CreateObject('adodb.stream')
    with (outputStream){
        Type = adTypeText;
        Charset = to;
        Open();
        WriteText( inputStream.ReadText );
        SaveToFile( outputFile, adSaveCreateOverWrite );
    }

    inputStream.Close()
    outputStream.Close()
```