# com.android.volley.parse error org.json.jsonexception value of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonArray in Android Volley

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, arrays

When I run this program I get this error . I don't know how to solve . Help me finding it Please.

This is my json_encode php code api.

```
  $i=0;
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
   $array[$i]=array(
        "news_id" => $row["news_id"], 
        "news_title" => $row["news_title"], 
        "news_abstract" => $row["news_abstract"], 
        "news_content" => $row["news_content"], 
        "news_date" => $row["news_date"], 
        "news_link" => $row["news_link"], 
        "news_image_link" => $row["news_image_link"], 
        "sources_name" => $row["sources_name"], 
        "category_name" => $row["category_name"],
        "news_visible" => $row["news_visible"]
    );
    $i++;
  }
    $json=json_encode($array, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

and my JsonArrayRequest of Android Volley JsonArrayRequest.

```
JsonArrayRequest newsRequest = new JsonArrayRequest( Url.getUrlJson(), new  Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse( JSONArray response ){
            Log.d( TAG, response.toString() );
            hidePDialog();

            // Parsing json
            for( int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++ ){
                try{
                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject( i );
                    News news = new News();
                     if( "1".equals( obj.getString( "news_visible" )) ){

                        news.setNews_id( obj.getString( "news_id" ) );
                        news.setNews_title( obj.getString( "news_title" ) );
                        news.setNews_abstract( obj.getString( "news_abstract" ) );
                        news.setNews_content( obj.getString( "news_content" ) );
                        news.setNews_date( obj.getString( "news_date" ) );
                        news.setNews_link( obj.getString( "news_link" ) );
                        news.setNews_image_link( obj.getString( "news_image_link" ));
                        news.setSources_name( obj.getString( "sources_name" ) );
                        news.setCategory_name( obj.getString( "category_name" ) );
                    }
                    newsList.add( news );
                }
                catch( JSONException e ){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: can you show your json structure?

Answer (score 1):

**Content Type**

```
<?PHP
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

See [Returning JSON from a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script).

**Byte Order Marker**

PHP is prone to return a *BOM* at the beginning of the response, when the `.php` file or any of its `include`s have UTF-8 character encoding.

For more information, see [this W3C answer](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark.en.php#problems) and section [UTF-8 BOM in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php).

One suggested way to prevent PHP from prepending a BOM is to [change the character set of your php file(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets) from UTF-8 to ASCII or ISO-8859-15.

Comment: Yes, you're getting what appears to be JSON data, but it doesn't conform to RFC 4627 (JSON specification). Maybe you can use a JSON validator to find the offending content. If you're still getting the same error message, try using as String response listener `Response.Listener<String>` instead of `Response.Listener<JSONArray>`.

Comment: but i will receive json array , if i receive string how can i do parsing.

example: JsonObject str=news JsonObject(response);
         JsonArray  array=str.getJsonArray(); this is mistake.

Comment: I agree, it would be a mistake. The invalid characters are the first three characters in the response body, before the JSON array starts. They are BOM (byte order marker) from PHP. For more information, find UTF-8 BOM in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: how can i edit character problem in php? i understood, normally i received json data but its telling me string because of character problem.

Comment: Save your .php source file (and any includes) with ASCII encoding instead of unicode.

Comment: when i was writing link to JSONLite i received **Unexpected token** from JSONLite validator. [link](http://jsonlint.com/)

this mistake is **<p>** html tag. How can i edit? this tag important in my code.

Comment: The unexpected token is not the **<p>** tag. It's the BOM marker, the first three bytes output by PHP. Save your .php source files as ASCII to solve the problem.

Comment: i don't know how to make. If you know i can send you my php code.

Comment: Read this post for best way to change text file encoding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting is a string and you are trying to assing it to jsonArray

Comment: i know this print is string, but how can i create json data in php