# Not getting response from server when using volley for listview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

Am trying to make listview using volley am not getting response from server it throws error JSONException this is my response from server:

`[{"UserName":"XXXX ","TaskID":1,"Subject":"fjsdgfgf","DueDate":"2016-01-06T00:00:00","Priority":0,"Owner":762,"OwnerName":null,"RepeatStatus":false,"TaskStatus":"In Progress","RelatedTo":null},{"UserName":"XXX","TaskID":2,"Subject":"test","DueDate":"2016-01-11T00:00:00","Priority":0,"Owner":762,"OwnerName":null,"RepeatStatus":false,"TaskStatus":"Not Started","RelatedTo":null}]`

Am not getting response it directly goes to Onerrorresponse it throws of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray as a beginner am really confused where am making mistake so far what i have tried is:

This is fragment where i make volley request:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 27-01-2016.
 */
public class Task extends Fragment {
    private List<Model_Task_List> model_task_lists;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task, container, false);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        model_task_lists=new ArrayList<Model_Task_List>();
        //Showing a progress dialog
        String Url="http://XXX.XX.X.XXX/XXX/GetActivitiesByUserID.svc/getlist/GetTask/762";
        //Creating a json array request
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Dismissing progress dialog
                        for(int i = 0; i<response.length(); i++) {
                            Model_Task_List model_task_list = new Model_Task_List();

                            try {
                                JSONObject   json =  (JSONObject) response
                                        .get(i);
                                model_task_list.setSubject(json.getString("Subject"));
                                model_task_list.setUserName(json.getString("UserName"));
                                model_task_list.setTaskStatus(json.getString("TaskStatus"));






                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            model_task_lists.add(model_task_list);
                        }

                        //Finally initializing our adapter
                        adapter = new Task_List_Adapter(model_task_lists,getContext());

                        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        //calling method to parse json array
                        // parseData(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("yog",error.toString());
                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        return view;
    }

}
```

This is my recyclerview adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class Task_List_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Task_List_Adapter.MyViewHolder>  {
    private List<Model_Task_List> dataSet;
   private    Context context;

    private static data yog;

    Model_Task_List modelTaskList=new Model_Task_List();

    public void remove(int position)
    {
        dataSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
    public void edit(int position){
        dataSet.set(position, modelTaskList);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(data listener) {
        this.yog = listener;
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        // ModelPersonal modelPersonal=new ModelPersonal();
        TextView textname;
        TextView textaddress;
        TextView textphnum;
        TextView textdegree;
        TextView textemail;
        ImageView call;
        data datas;

        public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject);
            this.textaddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            this.textphnum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(yog!=null){
                        yog.yog(itemView,getLayoutPosition());
                    }
                }
            });

            // this.imageViewIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        }



    }
    public interface data
    {
        void yog(View v,int position);
    }
    public Task_List_Adapter(List<Model_Task_List> data,Context context) {

        this.dataSet = data;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.task_list_view, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TextView textViewName = holder.textname;
        TextView textViewaddress = holder.textaddress;
        TextView textViewphnum = holder.textphnum;
        TextView textdegree = holder.textdegree;
        TextView textemail=holder.textemail;

        textViewName.setText("Subject:"+dataSet.get(position).getSubject());
        textViewaddress.setText("UserName"+dataSet.get(position).getUserName());
        textViewphnum.setText("Status:"+dataSet.get(position).getTaskStatus());


    }




    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }
}
```

This is my model class:

```
public class Model_Task_List {
    public String UserName;
    public String Subject;
    public String TaskStatus;

    public String getSubject() {
        return Subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        Subject = subject;
    }

    public String getTaskStatus() {
        return TaskStatus;
    }

    public void setTaskStatus(String taskStatus) {
        TaskStatus = taskStatus;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public Model_Task_List(String subject, String taskStatus, String userName) {
        Subject = subject;
        TaskStatus = taskStatus;
        UserName = userName;
    }
    public Model_Task_List(){

    }
}
```

My Jsonresponse:

`[{"UserName":"XXXXXX ","TaskID":1,"Subject":"fjsdgfgf","DueDate":"2016-01-06T00:00:00","Priority":0,"Owner":762,"OwnerName":null,"RepeatStatus":false,"TaskStatus":"In Progress","RelatedTo":null},{"UserName":"XXXXX","TaskID":2,"Subject":"test","DueDate":"2016-01-11T00:00:00","Priority":0,"Owner":762,"OwnerName":null,"RepeatStatus":false,"TaskStatus":"Not Started","RelatedTo":null}]`

I don't know where am making mistake can anybody helpme!!!

Log cat :

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:14940252
02-02 19:22:30.733 11678-11678/XX E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
02-02 19:22:30.733 11678-11678/XX E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
02-02 19:22:30.773 11678-11678/XX E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
02-02 19:22:30.773 11678-11678/XXE/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
02-02 19:22:30.793 11678-11678/xx W/Toast: From XXX, go ahead.
02-02 19:22:30.793 11678-11678/XX E/yog: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"UserName":"XX","TaskID":1,"Subject":"fjsdgfgf","DueDate":"2016-01-06T00:00:00","Priority":0,"Owner":762,"OwnerName":null,"RepeatStatus":false,"TaskStatus":"In Progress","RelatedTo":null},{"UserName":"XXX ","TaskID":2,"Subject":"test","DueDate":"2016-01-11T00:00:00","Priority":0,"Owner":762,"OwnerName":null,"RepeatStatus":false,"TaskStatus":"Not Started","RelatedTo":null}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
02-02 19:22:30.893 11678-11678/XXI/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@425c1690 time:14940540
```

Comment: post your jsonarray volley metthod

Comment: it is in fragment class

Comment: you are getting response from volley. you are getting JSONException while parsing

Comment: Yaaa when i debug my app it directly goes to error part

Comment: post your logcat output

Comment: when i changed to stringrequest its working fine

Answer (score 0):

I think the response you are getting from string is String. Please cross verify it at your server end

for more detail please below link
[com.android.volley.parse error org.json.jsonexception value of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonArray in Android Volley [SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400261/com-android-volley-parse-error-org-json-jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-st)

Comment: Then This is not a jsonarray?

Comment: then can i contiue with that or need to take a look at it

Comment: Thankz let me check it first but if u see the response as i posted above it looks like jsonarray then why am getting like this

Comment: ya but its not array you can cross verify it at your server end