# Angular not showing non-English letters in ui-router views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My web page contains Hebrew letters.
I've added this at the beginning of index.html:

```
<html lang="he">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
```

And all the Hebrew letters are shown correctly.

But when I load a state with ui-router, the letters in the view's html shown as symbols.
Part of the page shows Hebrew, and the ui-view part shows only symbols.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the view's files are saved using UTF-8 encoding. If you are using a text editor like Notepad++ you can go to **Prefferences -> Convert to UTF-8 without BOOM**

Usually you get this problem when a view file is saved with a different encode than you specified in your index.html by using HTML meta tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

In notepad you can also change the encoding in the "Save As..." dialog

If you are using linux. You may take a look at [Best way to convert text files between character sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)

Comment: Thanks!
As you said, index.html was on UTF-8 without BOM, but the other html templates were not. When I converted to UTF-8 without BOM, all letters are shown correctly.