# Encoding Spanish special characters in Page Title ASP.NET with UTF-8

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, utf-8

I use a Title in my aspx page with special characters (á,é,í,ó,ú, etc).

**Title="Información Económica"**

**Page.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Title="Información Económica" MasterPageFile="~/MyMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="InformacionEconomica.aspx.cs" Inherits="Company.WebIU.InformacionEconomica" %>
```

**web.config**

```
<globalization culture="es-ES" uiCulture="es-ES" enableBestFitResponseEncoding="false" enableClientBasedCulture="false" fileEncoding="UTF-8" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" responseHeaderEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

I have **meta** with `charset="utf-8"`

But the title is wrong:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
<meta name="tipo_contenido" content="text/html;" http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8" />

<title>
    Informaci?n Econ?mica
</title>
```

Works like using "acute"

```
Title="Informaci&oacute;n Econ&oacute;mica"
```

There are more 300 aspx pages, and I don't want replace all

```
á by &aacute;
é by &eacute;
í by &iacute;
ó by &oacute;
ú by &uacute;
etc...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you are saving files with correct encoding. If your are using `Visual Studio` take a look at "File -> Advanced Save Options" and select a Unicode aware `Encoding` like `Unicode (UTF-8 with signature)`.

Also make sure that your `aspx/html` file have following `meta`:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

Finally check your page via different browser and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 2):

Are your files saved as UTF-8? If not you need to convert them perhaps as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64889/246622).

Then add the following (from [MSDN - Select an Encoding for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization
      fileEncoding="utf-8"
      requestEncoding="utf-8"
      responseEncoding="utf-8"
      culture="en-US"
      uiCulture="es-ES"
    />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```