# Convert excel csv to plain text csv

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv

I have over two hundred individual files I need to load into a sql server database, and unfortunately they are all coming my way as excel csv files. Excel csv files are formatted corectly, but they use an UTF-8 or UTF-16 character format (I forget which), which trips up sql server when you try and bulk insert them. I have fiddled around with different arguments for my bulk insert but I run into other problems. The simplest solution has been to simply use the clipboard to copy them into another file, because the clip board always copies as plain text.

What I would really like to do is use a command line tool to convert all the files into plain text ascii character format in one pass. I am using a windows 7 operating system. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to convert text files between character sets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)

Comment: It is likely not the most efficient method, but I believe you could use a SSIS job for this task.

Comment: Look into using using WSH (Windows scripting host) to iterate over files in the directory and export/save them to the format you desire.  There are scripts out there that should point you in the right direction.  Something like this VBA will do it; just call it from your Excel object in WSH after you open the file, etc.: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="c:\MyFile.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False`

Comment: I'd just use powershell to `Get-Content` and then `Out-File` specifying the desired encoding.