# Change encoding of big csv file

Tags: database, csv

I have big .csv file and need to change its encouding. The problem is that size of file is 5 Gb. Its can't be opened by MS Excel or anything else. How can I do it? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: This can be easily Googled, no need to ask a new Stack Overflow question. Just search `<name of your OS> file change encoding `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to convert text files between character sets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)