# How To Convert Latin-1 To UTF-8 With Elixir?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, elixir

Elixir 1.3.0

Windows 10

Postgrex 0.11.2

Ecto 2.0.1

Postgres 9.4.4

I'm attempting to add records to a PostgreSQL database via Ecto. When I get to a string containing \x0087 it throws the following error:

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR (character_not_in_repertoire): invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x87
```

I'm pretty sure it's an issue with the file itself which as far as I can tell is encoded as Latin1.  This is the code I use to open the file and read it in:

```
:ok = :io.setopts(:standard_io, encoding: :latin1)
File.open!(file)
|> IO.binstream(:line)
```

The file opens fine and in fact several lines are processed just fine until it gets to a line that contains \x0087.

What I can't quite figure out is how to convert the line which is read in with latin1 encoding into UTF-8 encoding.  I found String.normalize which seems like it might help with the conversion but I know I'm grasping at straws.

I changed the `encoding:` parameter on the :`io.setopts` line to `:utf8` but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Is there some simple way to convert an ANSI/Latin1 encoded string to a UTF-8 encoded string?

Comment: I don't think the byte 0x87 is valid in latin1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout

Comment: It may not be.  The file isn't actually Latin 1.  It's actually Windows-1252.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really hesitant to answer my own question but I think using the techniques found in [this Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets) is the right answer here as well.  Basically need to convert from CP-1252 to UTF-8 and then everything works as expected.