# PHP/MySQL: Fixing utf8 text corrupted by implicit mysqli::set_charset('latin1') connection

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

So, for years and years, my PHP application has been connecting to MySQL using the default `latin1` charset. Even though I have some fields collated as `utf8_general_ci`, the actual data that is getting stored into them is some bastardized charset. For example:

Input: `♠ »`

is stored as `â™  Â»`

Now, when that data is retrieved over the same `latin1` connection and displayed on a page with encoding set as `utf8`, it displays just as it was entered: `♠ »` Why this is, I'm not 100% sure, but I'm guessing it's because whatever charset function which is screwing it up going in is fixing it coming out.

I want to fix my data. If I switch my connection charset using `mysqli::set_charset('utf8')`, the output is displayed as it is stored, i.e. `â™  Â»`

So, apparently I need to fix my existing data and then switch my connection charset.

How do I fix the existing bastardized data?

EDIT:

> I've discovered a way to emulate the corruption process that is
>   happening in a MySQL query: `SELECT CAST(BINARY '♠ »' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET latin1)` outputs `â™  Â»`
>
> Perhaps if I could figure out how to perform the reverse function I could use that query to fix the existing data.

EDIT 2:

> I've discovered such a function: `SELECT CAST(BINARY CAST('â™  Â»' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET latin1) AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8)` outputs `♠ »`
>
> My only concern now is what this will do to any data that already
>   happens to be actual utf8 data, which, for some reason, I do have in
>   my database. For example, `SELECT CAST(BINARY CAST('♠ »' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET latin1) AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8)` outputs (nothing)

Comment: here's [a great way to convert your database](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/convert-mysql-database-utf-8)

Comment: The character set of the fields in question is already `utf8_general_ci`. The problem is the data stored is seemingly corrupted due to the connection having been `latin1`

Comment: maybe mysqldump and [run the whole file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets) through a conversion?  or at least the affected tables -- i don't think your actual SQL commands wouldl be affected

Comment: I'm not sure what the conversion would be, however. I'm not really sure what "charset" the stored data qualifies as.

Comment: treat it as `latin1` and convert to `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: See my edit. Is there a way to do that in MySQL directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://jonisalonen.com/2012/fixing-doubly-utf-8-encoded-text-in-mysql/:

Auto-detecting function for converting maybe-corrupted latin1 text data to utf8:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION maybe_utf8_decode(str text charset utf8) 
RETURNS text CHARSET utf8 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
declare str_converted text charset utf8;
declare max_error_count int default @@max_error_count;
set @@max_error_count = 0;
set str_converted = convert(binary convert(str using latin1) using utf8);
set @@max_error_count = max_error_count;
if @@warning_count > 0 then
    return str;
else
    return str_converted;
end if;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Usage:

```
update mytable set mycolumn = maybe_utf8_decode(mycolumn);
```

Comment: I like the idea of a function to fix improperly encoded data and gave it a try after making a backup. However, it gave an error, *SQL Error (1366): Incorrect string value: '\xA0 Ther...' for column 'str' at row 4 *, in my MySQL client when I ran it.

Answer (score 2):

Before attempting to "fix" the data, make sure of what you have.  `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` -- `♠` might be 3 bytes: `E299A0`, or it might be more: `C3A2 E284A2 C2A0`.  The former is Mojibake; the latter is "double encoding".  The repairs are different.  More discussion [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831) and [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixing_double_encoding_).