# Auto-layout for UML diagrams

Tags: layout, uml, xmi

Is there a (preferably open-source) tool that can auto-layout UML diagrams that are given as XMI (just pure models, no graphical layer)? The result should be displayed in a GUI, or exported as SVG or similar.

Comment: You should have learned that SO is no Google-replacement, shouldn't you?

Comment: I have seen (and answered) many SO questions that can be easily googled. This one is not of this case. Google gives you lots of links about auto-layouting UML. I tried a number of them, but none gave me a usable tool that could input XMI and output some layout. Hence, I would prefer to build on someone else's reported positive experience.

Comment: See # 4 here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This is not a recommendation question! I just need a tool converting XMI (for UML)  to SVG. This is a very precise specification. Moreover, I doubt that there is a single tool that can do that. I would be happy if someone can prove my doubt wrong.

Comment: If you are not asking for a recommendation, then what are you asking for? The answer to "Is there a" can then only be "yes" or "no".

Comment: Even just a "yes" would help me. I do not understand your reservations. There are other questions of this type even in the community wiki, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets