# HTML Validation error for UTF-8

Tags: html, utf-8

Im running into a validation error which im usure of how to fix. When attaching this code to the validator it brings up this error. I am pretty new to HTML so i dont understand what it is i need to fix. Any help is appreciated!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Susan's Cactus</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <h1>Susan's Cactus Gardens</h1>

    <ul>
     <li>Caring for Succulents</li> 
     <li><h1>Propogating Cactus</h1></li>
     <li>Transplanting Cactus</li> 
     <li>Exotic Cactus</li>
    </ul>

    <p> Remember to water sparingly</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And the error code I get from the validator;

Error: Legacy encoding utf-16le used. Documents must use UTF-8.

Error: Internal encoding declaration utf-8 disagrees with the actual encoding of the document (utf-16).

From line 4, column 1; to line 4, column 22
l>↩↩↩

Comment: Have you tried converting the document into UTF-8 encoding? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64860/

Comment: Ok dumb question; how would I go about doing that? cause I can write it out as 'charset="UTF-8" ' is that just an identifier or does it set the instructions?

Comment: whoops nevermind, i figured it out and now its all validated and good. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Kronos what you  figured it out