# Ruby UTF-8 string to UCS-2 conversion

Tags: ruby, utf-8, ucs2

I have a UTF-8 string in my Ruby code.  Due to limitations I want to convert the UTF-8 characters in that string to either their escaped equivalents (such as `\u23`) or simply convert the whole string to UCS-2.  I need to explicitly do this to export the data to a file

I tried to do the following in IRB:

```
my_string = '7.0mΩ'
my_string.encoding
my_string.encode!(Encode::UCS_2BE)
my_string.encoding
```

The output of that is:

```
=> "7.0mΩ"
=> #<Encoding::UTF-8>
=> "7.0m\u2126"
=> #<Encoding::UTF-16BE>
```

This seemed to work fine (I got "ohm" as 2126) until I was reading data out of an array (in Rails):

```
data.each_with_index do |entry, idx|
  puts "#{idx} !! #{entry['title']} !! #{entry['value']} !! #{entry['value'].encode!(Encoding::UCS_2BE)}"
end
```

That results in the error:

> incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and UTF-16BE

I then tried to write a basic file conversion routine:

```
File.open(target, 'w', encoding: Encoding::UCS_2BE) do |file|
  File.open(source, 'r', encoding: Encoding::UTF_8).each_line do |line|
    output.puts(line)
  end
end
```

This resulted in all kinds of weird characters in the file.

Not sure what is going wrong.

Is there a better way to approach this problem of converting UTF-8 data to UCS-2 in Ruby?  I really wouldn't mind this actually being changed in the string to `\u2126` as a literal part of the string rather than the actual value.

Help!

#### Temporary Workaround

I monkey-patched this to do what I want.  It's not very elegant, but it does the job (and yes, I know it's not pretty... it's just a hack to get what I need):

```
def hacky_encode
  encoded = self
  unless encoded.ascii_only?
    encoded = scan(/./).map do |char|
      char.ascii_only? ? char : char.unpack('U*').map { |i| '\\u' + i.to_s(16).rjust(4, '0') }
    end.join
  end
  encoed
end
```

Which can be used:

```
"7.0mΩ".hacky_encode
```

Comment: It's not ruby, but what about using `iconv`? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets?rq=1)

Comment: Something like `string.unpack('U*').map { |i| "\\u" + i.to_s(16).rjust(4, '0') }.join` converts ALL characters, which is  not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Jared unfortunately I can't use `iconv`.  I get all kinds of weird characters as in the example above, but I cannot expect that to be installed on the machines it runs on.

Comment: When you say "export the data to a file" what type of data, and what type of file?  Can you just set the encoding in the file itself assuming it contains string data only?

Comment: Also, when you say "This resulted in all kinds of weird characters in the file." What are you using to read the file?  Whatever it is will need to deal with the encoding you use when creating the file. So there's that.  What is the intended purpose of the encoded file?

Comment: @lacostenycoder it's data where I don't know what will be coming in as it comes from different sources (unfortunately).  I was using just vi to try and read the files on my local machine.

Comment: What you have not explained is "who is the intended reader of the file?"  That should determine what format you want to encode TO. You shouldn't care what it looks like in vim so long as the intended user of the file will use the encoding you chose to output to.

Comment: @lacostenycoder it's intended to be machine readable but the file cannot be read on the opposing end of the spectrum (which I am assuming is a Microsoft SQL Server or C# implementation, I cannot be sure).