# file on UTF-8 and ISO8859-1

Tags: c, linux, file

Currently I have a program, that is trying to mimic the functionality of the (linux) file command. I parse a .txt file with some characters, and interpret it to its respective interpretation. However, I struggle in differentiating file, when it comes to ISO8859-1 (latin 1). As it converts ISO8859-1 characters as UTF-8 encodings instead (for instance the æ = e6, is encoded as c3 b8 instead?).

***When I make and pass this .txt into file:***

```
printf "æøå" > test.txt

file test.txt
```

***it returns simply:***

UTF-8 Unicode text, with no line terminators.

*** `od -c -tx1 test.txt` : returns ***

```
0000000 303 246 303 270 303 245
         c3  a6  c3  b8  c3  a5
0000006
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is the case, as the 'æøå' prefix is contained within ISO8859-1 encoding, but is then interpreted as a UTF8 encoding instead?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the output of `od -c -tx1 test.txt` to make sure the file really contains the expected hex values. BTW: Although you might want to implement something in C, your question is not related to C as it only mentions some shell commands.

Comment: @Bodo I corrected the question and shown the output of the file, when running the command. It makes sense it interprets the values are 2-bytes and then convert it to UTF8. This however is wierd for me, as the ISO8859-1 standard includes æøå in their range of 160-255.

Comment: It's unclear what you find weird in this. If your terminal encoding is UTF-8, wouldn't you expect file to be created in UTF-8? At what point do you expect ISO8859-1 to be involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously your file contains UTF-8 encoding.  For example `c3 a6` is the UTF-8 encoding for `æ`.

Probably your system locale is set to something with UTF-8. You can check this by running the `locale` command.

To convert your file from UTF-8 to ISO8859-1 you can use

```
recode utf8..iso8859-1 test.txt
```

After this you will get

```
$ od -c -tx1 test.txt            
0000000 346 370 345
         e6  f8  e5
0000003
```

As noted by [R..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r), you might have to install `recode` if it is not already installed. You can also use `iconv`, but this tool cannot do in-place modification. See also
[Best way to convert text files between character sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64860/10622916) and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10241/330217

Comment: Thanks that is probably what I missed :-) did not know about the recode command!

Comment: The `iconv` command is the standard way to do this. `recode` is a random utility that might or might not be installed.

Answer (score 2):

Bodo's answer is correct, but I think the root of your problem is the ambiguity of the term "character set". You're correct that all those characters are in the set of characters available in ISO-8859-1, but that's not terribly relevant; all it means is that you can faithfully represent them when encoding your text as ISO-8859-1. The ambiguity (some might even say misuse) of the word "set" here is why, in modern usage, the concept is called "*coded* character set" or preferably "character encoding", to reflect that the important aspect is how abstract characters in the set of available characters map to stored representations.

As sets, ISO-8859-1 is a subset of Unicode and thus a subset of the set of characters representable by UTF-8. But as encodings they don't agree anywhere except the subset that is ASCII. All other characters present in ISO-8859-1 are represented differently in UTF-8 than in ISO-8859-1; if this weren't the case, there would be no way to represent more than 256 characters since in ISO-8859-1 the meanings of all 256 bytes are assigned (to single characters).

As noted in Bodo's answer, æ is encoded in UTF-8 as `c3 a6`, whereas in ISO-8859-1 it's encoded as `e6`.