# snscrape decode tweet in python

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, cp1252

I'm trying to retrieve some tweets with snscrape but the JSON file generated is encoded 'cp1252'.
I coulnd't find in the documentation if there is a way to request the JSON file to be encoded as I whis but, shoudn't it be possible, how can I convert a quite big text file from cp1252 to UTF-8?
I've seen plenty of questions of this kind but they all explained how to print the correct text instead of storing it in a file.

This question is not a diplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets) as I'm not trying to do it by cmd but instead via python.

EDIT:
I'll try to better explain the situation: I'm retrieving tweets but they happen to contain unicode characters. This is an example of a sentence I'd like to decode:

> La mia vita \u00e8 fantastica
> I extracted the encoding of the file this sentence is written in and it is 'cp-1252'. I'm not sure anymore if this is a 'cp-1252' file containing unicode characters (is this even possible?), but I had no luck converting that "\u00e8" to my "è".

After the first comment, here's what I tried:

```
file = open(file_name_input, encoding='cp1252')
file_output = open(file_name_output, 'w')
for line in file:
    file_output.write(line.encode('utf-8').decode())
```

Comment: Do you have it as a file or as a bytestring?  If you have it as bytes, just use "ustr = bstr.decode('cp1252')" to get it as a unicode str.  If it's a file, open it using the cp1252 codec to get a unicode string.  In either case, you can write it to a file using any codec you like or manipulate it in memory.

Comment: I tried as suggested (edited the opening post) but without luck. Did I misunderstood your suggestion?

Comment: You are writing Unicode to the file, which is what I'm guessing you mean by "it didn't work".  You should open the output file with an encoding (`file_output = open(file_name_output, 'w', encoding='utf-8'`)), and write to it using `file_output.write(line)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to convert text files between character sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)

Comment: @cco I also tried your second tip but without luck, I still can't manage to decode that string. I added some infos in my opening post, maybe I wasn't explaining myself good enough :)