# HTTP Response encoding issue

Tags: rest, http, encoding, postman, response

I am trying to fetch a CSV file from a website (https://www.stocknet.fr/accueil.asp) using a GET request on the https URL. The response I get via Postman looks like this:

```
Type;Groupe Acc�s;Code;EOTP autoris�s;Familles EOTP autoris�es;Nom;Pr�nom;Adresse Mail;Agences autoris�es;D�p�ts autoris�s;Date cr�ation;Fournisseurs autoris�s;Classes autoris�es;Familles article
```

But when access the URL directly, my browser automatically downloads the file, and I open it on windows with a proper encoding:

```
Type;Groupe Accès;Code;EOTP autorisés;Familles EOTP autorisées;Nom;Prénom;Adresse Mail;Agences autorisées;Dépôts autorisés;Date création;Fournisseurs autorisés;Classes autorisées;Familles article
```

When I inspect the website HTML, I can see the tag `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />`

I tried using headers as such:

```
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Encoding: compress
Content-Encoding: deflate
Content-Encoding: identity
Content-Encoding: br
```

Nothing seem to return a response with the correct encoding.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ? Note that, whatever page of the website I try to fetch, I get this wrong encoding. It's not only with the CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

The server is returning content in iso-8859-1 and telling you it's iso-8859-1. You will not convince the server to return anything else. Your web browser contains code to convert encodings. If you want to have the content in a different encoding, you have to convert it yourself.

For ways how to do that, see:
[Best way to convert text files between character sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)

Comment: I see I got it all wrong ! Thanks. I'm trying to convert it using PL/SQL, and I can't seem to make it work though. Trying something like `convert(l_response, 'WE8ISO8859P1', 'WE8MSWIN1252')` .. You have any idea ?

Comment: @Kabulan0lak I don't know PL/SQL and have no way to try it, sorry. Looks like that could be a new question. Why 1252 as dest though? I don't think that can express an `è`. Didn't you want UTF8?

Comment: It corresponds to the NLS parameter of my Oracle instance. Thanks you for everything! I'm going to try out more stuff then post another question if really needed.